# Bootstrap 4.3 cards not showing correctly in Internet explorer

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I'm using Bootstrap 4.3.1 and trying to create a view with cards. the problem i'm getting is the cards are displaying perfectly fine in chrome and other browsers while its not displaying correctly in Internet Explorer 11

```html
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 pt-3 pb-3">
                        <div class="card card-body bg-light">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate.

                            <hr />
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="pl-2">
                                    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="ml-auto pr-2 text-success">
                                    <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                                    Complete
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 pt-3 pb-3">
                        <div class="card card-body bg-light">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate.

                            <hr />
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="pl-2">
                                    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="ml-auto pr-2 text-success">
                                    <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                                    Complete
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 pt-3 pb-3">
                        <div class="card card-body bg-light">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate.
                            <hr />
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="pl-2">
                                    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="ml-auto pr-2 text-success">
                                    <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                                    Complete
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 pt-3 pb-3">
                        <div class="card card-body bg-light">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate.
                            <hr />
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="pl-2">
                                    <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="ml-auto pr-2 text-success">
                                    <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                                    Complete
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

you can see in the images in which i'm getting the correct output in chrome while in IE its squeezed out.

[image: Chrome Working Image]

IE 11 output

[image: Internet Explore not working image]

Comment: Am i missing something i'm seeing IE 10+ supported.. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I added your code to the starter template of bootstrap and it is working fine. Make sure that you are importing the correct files:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 pt-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card card-body bg-light">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate.

                <hr />
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="pl-2">
                        <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="ml-auto pr-2 text-success">
                        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                        Complete
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 pt-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card card-body bg-light">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate.

                <hr />
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="pl-2">
                        <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="ml-auto pr-2 text-success">
                        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                        Complete
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 pt-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card card-body bg-light">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate.
                <hr />
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="pl-2">
                        <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="ml-auto pr-2 text-success">
                        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                        Complete
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 pt-3 pb-3">
            <div class="card card-body bg-light">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra codeply varius quam sit amet vulputate.
                <hr />
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="pl-2">
                        <i class="far fa-clock"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="ml-auto pr-2 text-success">
                        <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
                        Complete
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

IE 11 output:

[image]